# Generating a querydsl values statement

Tags: sql, querydsl

We have a need to generate a subquery such as:
`VALUES 1,12,923,459, ..., 21263` 
within a larger querydsl query, but I can see no way to generate this.

Currently we are using a bit of a hack with 
        (select 10090)
        union
        (select 10091)
        union
        (select 10100)
        union
but that has a large performance penalty (in postgresql).

Comment: Actually the query would need to be `VALUES (1), (2),...`  etc.

Comment: Where those values came from? Any table? Application parameters? Add more details so we can be a better help

Comment: The values are coming out of an application. It is a big application, think report writer, but it isn't exactly that. We are generating SQL from free form user input and generating some unreasonably large and complex queries.

This bit can't be done with at JOIN to other tables or IN clause which we would otherwise do because the data is held elsewhere in an incompatible form.

Comment: Hi, @TrevorCampbell, have you managed to figure this out?